# Fixed element out of screen on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am developing a widget which could be embedded into the page as an iframe (iframe will be injected and styled via javascript). Iframe should be placed in bottom right corner. I can only control the style of an iframe.

I have created following demo page which demonstrates the problem in test host page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="greeting" style="width:1000px">Loading...</p>
         <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5%; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: transparent; border: 0px none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1000000;right: 5%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

On desktop browser this code works fine, but on (some) mobile devices the iframe is not visible on the screen. If I try to highlight an element its placed on gray area.

Why is happening this and how can I style an iframe so that will be placed on bottom right corner?

Edit: this is a screenshot from Galaxy S3 emulation (Chrome). Iframe is invisible in gray area. I think its the same on physical Nexus 5X device.

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a name of the mobile device in where the iframe is not visible? I would also want to check it as well

Comment: @PhilipDomingo : i have updated question above.

Comment: what about embed your widget about `<iFrame>` into the owners Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1000px` width had been given to `#greeting` , that's why the element out of your mobile width ,you can simply fix this like using media Queries. `992 width` starting the portrait view of devices

```css
@media (max-width:992px){
 #greeting { width:100% !important; }  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="greeting" style="width:1000px">Loading...</p>
         <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5%; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: transparent; border: 0px none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1000000;right: 5%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I already said, I'm developing ONLY widget (an iframe), so I dont have access or I cant modify parent page. It seems that this particular page is a little bit "odd" - it has viewport tag for responsive design, but its not responsive (fixed widths). As I investigated its not possible to address my issue without changing layout/css of the parent page (which I cant), so the owner of a page will have to address this issue (if it will want to have our widget). I will accept this answer even though it doesnt solve my issue, but I will know how to support this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based from my investigation, the gray area that shows up in the chrome emulator is caused by the style of the paragraph html tag:

```
`<p id="greeting" style="width:1000px">Loading...</p>`
```

I believe the gray area shows up because you have a style of `width:1000px` in where the total size of the emulator, **Galaxy S3** for example, only have a maximum width of 360px. But if you remove the `width: 1000px` style in the paragraph element, you can see that the frame is being properly shown in the bottom right corner of the screen.

You can check it with the sample below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="greeting" style="width: 100px">Loading...</p>
         <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5%; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: transparent; border: 0px none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1000000;right: 5%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that doesn't help me a lot. When I prepared this example I also noticed this. The problem is that (as I already said), that I CANNOT change the main page, because I'm not an owner of the page -> I am only developing a widget which will be embedded into the page via iframe (and JS).

Comment: I also tried another thing. On this example page I have removed my Iframe and I embedded zopim (online chat) widget, which also uses fixed positioning. And it also doesn't work (its hidden in gray area). If I remove either the meta (viewport) tag or width on paragraph than it is visible. It seems that this combination is causing problems -> on the other hand it is obvious that responsive design and fixed width isn't the way to go. So the question is: is it possible to overcome this problem without modifying owner page or not?

Comment: Interesting! The meta tag combined with the width on paragraph seems to  make the body scaled. But the fixed element still fixed in the whole window. So its position is out of the body.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but what if -- instead of setting the position as `bottom: 5%; right: 5% -- you calculate the position from the top left based on viewport width and viewport height.  Something like:

```
top: calc(100vh - 200px);
left: calc(100vw - 200px);
```

Answer (score 0):

See **[THIS DEMO IN YOUR MOBILE](http://miipro.com/test.htm)**

**Change:-**

add following style to handle mobile browser

**Reason:-**

The mobile renders the html in mobile compatible mode which injects its own style to the higher width elements. thats why the page works in an unintended way in mobile compatible mode. if you handle it in your html itself, then it leaves the style of your page how you intended to view.

Thats why if you click `Request desktop site` in chrome setting your code itself works fine

```
/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #greeting {
        width:100% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
 <style>
/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #greeting {
        width:100% !important;
    }
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="greeting" style="width:1000px">Loading...</p>
         <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="position: fixed; bottom: 5%; width: 200px; 

height: 200px; background: tranparent; border: 0px none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1000000;right: 

5%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```